# TCP connection: Specifying own host address and sending replicated packages to another host

Tags: c#, controller, led

So, I have the following Problem: I am trying to connect my C# Software to a Micro Controller that's specifically designed for LED Signs. It communicates with a Software via TCP, receiving the informations from it as clear text. The reason behind me, trying to write my own software, is attempting to build an automated system around it, which makes the whole thing more versatile. However, I ran into a few issues:

The Controller is sending its acknowledge responses to a pre-defined IP address, which I know. How can I write my program that it catches the responses from this specific host to that specific address?

Secondly, I want to replicate the order of the tcp packets sent via the software to make the controller belive the packet comes from said software. There is no encryption whatsoever, only the order of the packages sent is important. How can I replicate these packages?

Comment: You want a Two Port application.  1) A client that connect to a Sign 2) A Listener/Server that accepts connection from the Controller.  You are going to have to change the Control to send to the machine where your new application is running.  You will also have to use a different port number for each port.

Comment: @jdweng Sadly this is not possible. I have to basically brute force my way into an already existing system, a not at all documented micro controller that runs a tiny tcp server which accepts inputs from a computer software via tcp. I was able to capture this packet transfer, and I'm trying to recreate it. I can already communicate with the controller via tcp and a few software tweeks, I just need help with the packet replication since I don't have much knowledge of string-to-hex conversions.

Comment: You need bytes so to convert a string to a byte array : byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string);

Comment: @jdweng This helped me a little already. I'm having quite the tough nut to crack here, this sure won't be easy, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help you solve issues.